# How to select and order by id and get multiple results?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I have one database `clients` and two tables: `business` and `categories`.

The site is a classified ads placement, `business` contains:

```
Field            Type          Collation           Null    Key     Default          Extra   Privileges                       Comment  
---------------  ------------  ------------------  ------  ------  ---------------  ------  -------------------------------  ---------
id               int(11)       (NULL)              NO      PRI     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
name             varchar(255)  latin1_swedish_ci   NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references             
category_id      int(11)       (NULL)              YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references
```

And this is `category`

```
Field   Type          Collation          Null    Key     Default  Extra   Privileges                       Comment  
------  ------------  -----------------  ------  ------  -------  ------  -------------------------------  ---------
id      int(11)       (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
name    varchar(255)  latin1_swedish_ci  NO              (NULL)           select,insert,update,references
```

Now, there are thousands of records in `business` but only `10` records in `category`.

I need to fetch around 100 records from `business` but their `category_id` should be from `1-10`

In other words, the 100 records would be like this

`id 1 category_id 1`
`id 2 category_id 1`
`id 11 category_id 2`
`id 21 category_id 3`

---

I have tried these two methods, but they don't work

#### first attempt

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `category_id` FROM business GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY category_id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

#### second attempt

```
SET @random := (SELECT FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 10)));
SELECT `id`, `name`, `category_id` FROM business GROUP BY @random ORDER BY category_id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

The above examples don't work, because I only get one record back.

Comment: Does you need strongly 10 records for each of 10 categorise? If so calculate record numbers in each category separately, then select only those records which number is not over 10. To enumerate records on tagged server versions you may use user-defined variables.

Comment: I wish that was as easy as it sounds, but i'll try

Comment: Try to look at search result by search string `[Mysql] row_number`.

Comment: Not wise to play games with numbers.